# Limit function/constructor arguments to members of a particular type

Tags: c++

If I have a templated class that takes another class as a parameter and which is constructed from a particular type, is there anyway to limit its range of possible construction values to those that are only members of the parameter class?

So, if I have

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(int v)
        : value(v) {}

    int value;
};
```

and,

```
struct Bar {
    static const int valid1 = 6;
    static const int valid2 = 9;
    static const int valid3 = 42;
};
```

can I limit the valid values that can be passed to the constructor of `Foo<Bar>` to `Bar::valid1` ... `Bar::valid3`?

With this example, I could use an enum in `Bar` that has a specific name, specified in `Foo`'s constructor which would take members of the enum rather than plain ints, but this has the problem that any value can be cast to the enum, so it is easily broken, and more importantly is not extendible to non-integral types.

A strong typedef would do the trick I think, and I believe there's one in boost but I'm looking for solutions I can implement myself with the standard library if possible.

I thought about function pointers, so instead of `static const int`'s in `Bar` I would have functions that return the values and the constructor of `Foo` wold accept a function pointer. However static functions behave just like globals with repect to function pointers so there is no `Bar` qualification required when calling it in `Foo` so any global function returning an int could be used. It could be made to work by not using static functions in `Bar` and maintaining an instance of `T [=Bar]` in `Foo` and calling the function pointer against this instance, but this seems a bit messy, functions that naturally should be static are not, and I have an instance of a struct which really should be just a container for constants.

I wonder if there is a standard way of doing this, or what you would recommend.

Comment: What if `T` is not `Bar`? Also, for what it's worth, if someone decides to cast an integer value to an enum, if something breaks that's their own fault.

Comment: `T` will always be of a type equivalent to `Bar`. It is generated through a macro. The values of `validX` and the actual names `validX` are not known in advance though. `Foo` is not meant to be used except via the macro. The fact I have to use macros at all is filling me with a little dread in itself I must admit, but for the moment thats what I've got to work with.

Comment: @tjm: If you don't mind, could you add a non-Bar example? And perhaps an even larger picture? (What's Foo, what do the Bar-types represent?) There might be a better way.

Comment: Whenever you need an integer with a limited range of possible values, consider using an `enum`.

Comment: @GMan: thanks for your interest, It's basically the same situation I had here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273354/accessing-a-static-member-that-has-the-same-name-as-an-inner-type where, `Foo` = `Sequence` and `Bar` = `mySequence`.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see the big picture. :) What are the values used for, where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather hackish solution if you know the valid numbers you're going to use at compile time. If there's chance that the valid numbers can change, it won't be much use.

Start by using a named-type template parameter rather than the constructor.

```
template <typename T, int Bar>
struct Foo {
private:
    Foo() { }
};
```

Notice I've made the constructor private. You won't be able to instantiate this class (or you'll get a compile time error, which is nice).

To instantiate the ones you want, we can specialize the template to those values only, and provide public constructors so you can instantiate them.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, 6>{
    Foo() : value(6) { 
    }
    int value;
};
```

It's now valid to use `Foo<int, 6> foo`, but `Foo<int, 7> foo` etc wont compile. Do this for each contsraint. (And yes, I realize it is ugly). You can reduce this syntax a lot by creating another class, let's call it `FooInternal` - which you will implement all your generic code inside, and having each of your specialized classes derive from it. Give it a protected constructor to prevent instantiation.

```
template <typename T, int Bar>
struct FooInternal {
protected:
    FooInternal() : value(Bar) {
    }
public:
    int value ;
};
```

The specializations can then be reduced to one liners.

```
template<typename T> struct Foo<T, 9> : FooInternal<T, 9> {};
template<typename T> struct Foo<T, 42> : FooInternal<T, 42> {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my other answer, I read the question again and think it's suitable for this. Along the same lines though, you can create a struct with a private constructor, and another nested one with a protected constructor. Each of your valid numbers can derive from the internal struct. This makes a kind of strongly-typed enum, which I guess is what you want.

```
struct Bar {
private:
    Bar() { }

    struct BarInternal {
    protected:
        BarInternal(int v) : value(v) {}
        int value;
    public:
        operator int() { //Allow cast back to int.
            return value;
        }
    };
public:
    struct Valid1 : public BarInternal {
        Valid1() : BarInternal(6) { }
    };

    struct Valid2 : public BarInternal {
        Valid2() : BarInternal(9) { }
    };
};
```

Then adjust your template to take a Bar::BarInternal in it's constuctor.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(Bar::BarInternal v)
        : value(v) {}

    int value;
};
```